# Cannot read property ‘params’ of undefined (React Router 4)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a route set up to render a component:

```js
<Route exact path="/page/:id" location={this.props.location} key={this.props.location.key} render={({ location }) => (
    <PageStart key={this.props.location.key} />
)} />
```

Then inside that component (PageStart) I have:

```js
this.props.match.params.id
```

But it throws an error:

```js
Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

Passing props when simply calling `component={}` seems to work fine but not in a render function. Why?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Because with `render` you are not passing the default props passed by the router into component, like match, history etc.

When you write this:

```js
<PageStart key={this.props.location.key} />
```

It means no `props` value in `PageStart` component.

Write it like this:

```js
render = {props => <PageStart {...props} key={this.props.location.key} /> } />
```

Now `{...props}` will pass all the value into `PageStart` component.

Comment: When you explain it, it becomes obvious. Thanks!

Comment: Why is it needed to pass - `this.props.location.key`?

Comment: @Hussain not sure, i copied that part from ques :)

Comment: Finally somebody that explained it for class usage!

Comment: @Hussain I think adding the key gives the component a unique identifier so React  can know to identify each component in its virtual dom for fast re-rendering. From my understanding, only lists require it but it's possible the use of keys for general components extends as well. See https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Because you don't pass any `match` property to PageStart. You give it a `key` but no `match`.
Try this:

```js
<Route 
    exact 
    path="/page/:id" 
    location={this.props.location} 
    key={this.props.location.key} 
    render={({ 
        location, 
        match 
    }) => (
        <PageStart key={this.props.location.key} match={match} />
    )} 
/>
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I found out that it is no longer `match` in the router props, it is now `computedMatch`.

I.E: `this.props.computedMatch.params.id`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 3):

The error says the `match` prop is undefined. That's correct, there is no `match` prop here:

```js
<PageStart key={this.props.location.key} />
```

So we need to pass it in. The `render` function receives a bunch of props from react-router, and all of them need to be passed further down. So, spread them first, and then add your own props:

```js
<Route
  exact
  path="/page/:id"
  location={this.props.location}
  key={this.props.location.key}
  render={(props) => (
    <PageStart {...props} key={this.props.location.key} />
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

please check for the routename provided

```
const AuthNavigattor = createStackNavigator(
  {
    logins: {screen: LoginScreen},
    splash: {screen: SplashScreen},
    register: {screen: RegisterScreen},
    forgetPassword: {screen: ForgetPasswordScreen},
    mobileNumber: {screen: MobileNumberScreen},
    codeEnter: {screen: CodeEnterScreen},
    changePassword: {screen: ChangePasswordScreen},
    // dashboard: { screen: Drawer }
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: "splash",
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
const ProfileNavigattor = createStackNavigator(
  {
    logins: {screen: LoginScreen},
    splash: {screen: SplashScreen},
    register: {screen: RegisterScreen},
    forgetPassword: {screen: ForgetPasswordScreen},
    mobileNumber: {screen: MobileNumberScreen},
    codeEnter: {screen: CodeEnterScreen},
    changePassword: {screen: ChangePasswordScreen},
    // dashboard: { screen: Drawer }
  },
  {
    // initialRouteName: "splash",
    headerMode: 'none',
  },
);
```

here there is repitition of same route name like logins, splash etc which might be the reason for this error. Rename this unique will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

try this please. i hope it can solve the issue.

```
render = {props => <PageStart {...props} key={this.props.location.key} /> } />
```