# match.params.id returning undefined in react arrow functional components

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am creating a simple portfolio application for which I require a separate screen for each project from a list of projects. In doing so when I try to get the Id of that project from the URL using `match.params.id`, it gives a `TypeError : Cannot read property 'params' of undefined`.
My code ProductScreenById:

```
import db from '../firebase'

export const ProjectScreenById = ({ match }) => {

    const pid = match.params.id

    return (
        <div>
            hello world
        </div>
    )
}
```

My ProjectListScreen:

```
import db from '../firebase'
import { Row, Col, Spinner } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Project } from '../components/Project'

export const ProjectScreen = () => {
    
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

    useEffect(() =>{
        db.collection('projects').orderBy('index','asc').onSnapshot(snapShot => {
            setProjects(snapShot.docs.map(doc => ({id:doc.id, project:doc.data()})))
        })
    },[])

    const windowWidth = () => {
        const { innerWidth:width, innerHeight:height } = window;
        return { width, height }
    }
    
    return (<>
            {projects.length===0 ? 
                <div className='mt-5 pt-5'>
                    <Spinner animation='border' style={{ width:100, height:100 }}/> 
                </div>
                : (
                <Row style={{ overflowX: 'hidden', width:'100%' }} className='pl-5 pt-5'>
                    {projects.map(project => (
                        <Col key={project.project.index} className='mr-2 mb-5'>
                            <Project 
                                description={project.project.description.split('.')}
                                title={project.project.title}
                                features={project.project.features.split('.')}
                                git={project.project.git}
                                link={project.project.link}
                                index={project.project.index}
                                id={project.id}
                                stack={project.project.stack}
                          />
                        </Col>
                    ))}
                </Row>
                )}
        </>
    )
}
```

My Project Component:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Card, Image } from 'react-bootstrap'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'

export const Project = ({ description, features, git, index, link, stack, title, id }) => {
    
    const images = [
        './images/ecom/display.png',
        './images/ytclone/display.png',
        './images/calculator/display.png',
        './images/todo/display.png',
        './images/expense/display.png',
        ' ./images/techS/display.png',
        './images/tictactoe/display.png',
        './images/canvas/display.png',
        './images/linked/display.png'
    ]
    
    return (
        <Card className='py-3 px-5' style={{ height:'100%'}} sm={12}>
            <Image src={images[parseInt(index)]} style={{ width:'100%', border:'0.5px ridge rgb(219,219,219)' }} className='image' />
            <b>{title}</b>
            <div style={{ textAlign:'left' }} className='mb-2' >
                <b>Description:</b>
                {description.map(d=>(
                <li key={description.indexOf(d)}>{d}</li>
            ))}</div>
            <div style={{ textAlign:'left' }} className='mb-2' id='features'>
                <b>Features:</b>
                {features.map(f=>(
                    <li key={features.indexOf(f)}>{f}</li>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div style={{ textAlign:'left' }} className='mb-2' id='stack'>
                <b>Tech Stack:</b>
                {stack.map(s=>(
                    <li key={stack.indexOf(s)}>{s}</li>
                ))}
            </div>
            <div style={{ textAlign:'left' }} className='mb-2' id='git' >
                <b>Git Repo: </b>
                <a href={git.slice(0,5)==='https' ? git : '/projects'} target='_blank'>{git}</a>
            </div>
            <div style={{ textAlign:'left' }} className='mb-2' id='link' >
                <b>Project link: </b>
                <a href={link==='Upcoming' || link==='N/A' ? '/projects' : link}>{link}</a>
            </div>
            <Link to={`/projects/${id}`} className='view'><b>View Project & Project Details</b></Link>
        </Card>
    )
}
```

App.js:

```
import './App.css';
import { ContactScreen } from './screens/ContactScreen'
import { ProjectScreen } from './screens/ProjectScreen'
import { Header } from './components/Header'
import { Footer } from './components/Footer'
import { ProjectScreenById } from './screens/ProjectScreenById'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Header/>
      
      <Router>
  
          <Route path="/contact" component={ContactScreen} exact/>

          <Route path="/projects" component={ProjectScreen} exact />

          <Route path="/projects/:id" component={ProjectScreenById} exact/>

      
      </Router>
      
      <Footer/>
    </div>
  );
}
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46197178/11583240) should help you out, but until then, here's a quick hack for it with `useLocation`:

```js
const location = useLocation()
const ID = location.pathname.split("/projects/")[1]
```

Comment: I got the solution by using useParams() but the catch is in the previous project the match.params.id worked fine but in this it is causing problem, but thanks for the help.

Comment: Well that can depend on a lot of factors like namely what `props` you passed into your component as well as what you used for routing. Anyway, if my answer helped you mark it as correct. Good day!